# Hiding the featured image for a specific post category in wordpress (single post)?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am looking for a solution using css or PHP to hide the featured image for (a single post page/template) in a specific category. For example, if a post is in the category "resources" I still want the featured image to show on the blog page, but once the image/link is clicked, I want it to be hidden on the actual post.

I have tried:
.category-resources .post-thumbnail {  display: none;  }

unsuccessfully. Any ideas? I am using the default twenty twenty four theme (gutenberg block builder) if that helps narrow it down.

Comment: _"I have tried: `.category-resources .post-thumbnail { display: none; }` unsuccessfully."_ - have you verified that the selector actually works as intended? And if so, have you checked if the `display` property for the element wasn't perhaps overwritten by another rule, with higher specificity?

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what/where is applying what CSS to that featured image? I don't see how we can solve this without access to that, but you can.